# How to echo picture using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with this guys,
I have this code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}")
{
    echo '<center><img src="admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}" width="100" height="100"/>'.'</center>';     
    // echo "success!:)";
} 
else 
{
    echo "photo not uploaded";
}
```

the problem here is when i echo it and use its tmpname i am having an error in this section

```
<img src="admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}" width="100" //....
```

the userfile is underlined in red. Is it wrong to use its tempname in echoing it?
help me please...

Comment: Are you sure that the if-statement is correct? Looks like you cut something off from the end.

Comment: yes i am, in fact it copies the picture that i picked..

Comment: what programm do you use for coding ? doesnt it have syntax highlighter ?

Comment: @Dwza : What you mean of `what programm do you use for coding ?`

Comment: @Ranjith i use notepad++ what actually has syntax highlighting, the only one i know that hasnt highlighting is the regular notepad or may word. i have see people coding in word :D and if you not familier with the source or the coding languages ssyntax than you may should use a IDE for coding.

Comment: @Dwza : That's fine.. Does Notepad++, word or notepad is program? You need to spell like this `what editor or IDE do you use for coding ?

Comment: @Ranjith So you think that an Editor or IDE is not a program ?

Comment: @Dwza : Yeah. It's a program. But in here it will get confuse the user. So editor or IDE is apt

Comment: i guess this will be his smallest problem :) but ok, may you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `echo` statement like this,

```
echo '<center><img src="admin/gallery/'.{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}.'" width="100" height="100"/>'.'</center>';
```

Also your `if` checks showing incorrectly.

May be like  this,

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']")
{
 .....
}
```

Comment: i did that already.. the problem is when change this '{' underlined in read

Comment: Did you add the end if condition `name']")`

Answer (score 0):

try with proper `quoting` and `if()`

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
    echo '<center><img src="admin/gallery/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].'" width="100" height="100"/>'.'</center>';     
    // echo "success!:)";
    }else
    echo "photo not uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have a problems with your `'` and `"`

i would do it like this

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
echo "<center><img src='admin/gallery/{$filename}' width='100' height='100' /></center>";
```

this should do it

total source is

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}")
{
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    echo "<center><img src='admin/gallery/{$filename}' width='100' height='100' /></center>";
}
else
{
    echo "photo not uploaded";
}
```

Comment: in this code i am not having error, but the problem is the picture does not showing

Comment: @user3737597 sorry, try again, had a  lil typo :D

Comment: @user3737597 i edited my post, copy it again and try it. this should work now. does it ?

Comment: got it.. thanks bro. another question, can we show the selected picture directly without pressing the submit button? can we use onchange? or onclick?

Comment: first of all, if this question was helpful, you can vote this up. and if you have another question. go and ask a new oen to not get people confused.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. You can use php in html attributes and tags

```
<img src="admin/gallery/<?php {$_FILES['userfile']['name']} ?>" width="100" />
```

Comment: actually he is in php so no need to extra escape it

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}")
```

And

```
echo "<img src='admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}' width='100'...";
```

or better close php with an `?>`then

```
<img src='admin/gallery/<?php echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];?>' width='100'...
```

Comment: first of all he is in php so why should he close the php tag to show an image? and the second, you will not see an image if you dont use quotes in the associativ part of the php array. the right word here is correct quoting!

Comment: I have added it as an alternative code and thanks for the quotes ,Fixed.

Comment: this will still give an error as you quote two different things with the same quote. `'admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}'`