# How to echo image directly in php?

Tags: php, html, image-processing

How can we echo a selected image in php without clicking a submit button? I have this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submiti'])){
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type']; 
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        if(in_array($fileType, $image_array)){
            if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxFileSize){
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],"C:/xampp/htdocs/new/admin/gallery/{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}")){
                    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                    echo "<center><img src='admin/gallery/{$filename}' width='100' height='100' /></center>";
                }else
                    echo "photo not uploaded";
             }else{
                echo ' Error :  File size exceeds the maximum limit ';
            }    
        }else{
            echo 'File size exceeds the maximum limit';
        }
    }
```

Can we make it

```
if(isset($_POST['userfile'])){ //...
```

something like that? so that the picture will automatically show? i tried it but i don't know the right way. can you please help me?

Comment: What problem you facing with above code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256833/how-to-echo-picture-using-php

Comment: the above code is working but i want is, how can we make it showing without clicking the submit button?

Comment: @User3737597 you have already asked this question 3 hours ago..

Comment: the other link is the one echoing the image by clicking the submit button

Comment: yes but it is different problem

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript.. not with PHP.

Comment: yes i tried it but not working using oncahnge, is it really onchange or what? onclick?

Comment: Either of them.. it is more about the JavaScript behind that what shows the image. Can you show the (JavaScript) code you currently have

Comment: if(!isset($_POST['userfile']))
                {
<div class="upload"> 
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">
                 <table><tr>
                    <td><input class="up" onchange="javascript:document.forms['neww'].submit()" name="userfile" type="file" /></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="Submit"/><br /></td>
                 </tr></table>
            </form>

something like this the userfile is the file input name

Comment: sorry i don't know how to write code in comment

Answer (score 0):

In order to load an image without submiting it through the form you need to use javascript.
PHP is a server side language and it can work only with files you upload on the server.

In order to accomplish what you want, using javascript, you need to use canvases.

Here is a good example of how to do it with jQuery:
[Dynamically add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944382/dynamically-add-image-to-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean, but if you want ... `IF` a certain value to be `NOT EMPTY` you show a picture, right?

This sounds to me like an if-else statement you should use.

```
if ($_POST['userfile'] != "")  // if the variable is NOT empty, execute the following statement. 
{    
    echo "<center><img src='admin/gallery/". $filename. "' width='100' height='100' /></center>";
} else {
    echo "There is no variable specified";
}
```

You can work in some sort of procedure.

Comment: i had it working it has default picture if it is not yet set, what i want is when i choose image it will automatically show the image at the browser even not clicking the submit button

Comment: Then use the code outside of the code you wrote. I mean, the isset function up there is the checker of your `'submiti'` button. So at the point where it normally should be shown you should define a variable where the image name is in. If the image name is empty, show default, if not, show the picture you uploaded. Its a bit of reverse engineering what you want, cause your question lacks serious explination and definition.

Comment: Had to read 5 times your comment before I understood. It needs to save the image so everytime you refresh you pick that image, right? If so, save it to a database, and make a query to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<img src="' . $image_path . '" alt="Screen shot" /></p>';
```

u cannot directly show an image by using echo.
put image tag inside echo